# "Frette" est-il plus froid que "froid"?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec, nuance

Au Québec, on utilise assez généralement la prononciation /fʁɛt/, et l’on écrit *frette* ou *frète*, pour **froid**. On indique au *Glossaire du parler français au Canada*, qu’il s’agit de la prononciation du XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, et on définit le terme par froid, tout simplement.

[image]

Il ne faudrait pas pour ça croire que la prononciation habituelle est inconnue ou exotique au Québec. Nous utilisons aussi /fʁwa(d)/ comme ailleurs dans la Francophonie.

À quelques reprises dans ma vie, surtout dans le Sud de la province, j’ai entendu qu’il existait une nuance entre froid et frète, à savoir que frète est plus froid que froid. Le contraste est même repris par certains journalistes, par exemple au [Journal de Québec](https://www.journaldequebec.com/2009/01/15/de-froid-a-frette) en janvier 2009 :

> Jeudi, à Québec, il ne faisait plus froid, mais « frette », vraiment frette.

Mon expérience linguistique ne m’a pas exposé outre mesure à cette distinction, mais elle me semble assez naturelle et facile à comprendre quand elle confronte en une même phrase les deux prononciations.

- Où, quand et comment est apparue cette idée que le frette est une version amplifiée du froid ?
- Existe-t-il des endroits du Québec où la nuance est permanente, où les deux notions sont séparées ou ne se recoupent que minimalement, où l’on n’est pas tenu de mettre l’autre en contraste pour transmettre la nuance recherchée ?
- Est-il possible de donner les raisons, probables ou possibles, qui ont conduit à cette gradation (tiède-frais-froid-frète) plutôt qu’à l’autre possible (tiède-frais-frette-froid) ?

Comment: Voilà une question qui aura besoin d'un québécois pour obtenir une réponse je pense, je découvre pour ma part le mot "frette"

Comment: @LaurentS. Sait-on jamais. Quelques usagers d’Europe ont su à l’occasion capturer la situation du français d’Amérique de manière assez éclairée, même sans en avoir l’expérience personnelle. Il est vrai néanmoins que les ressources sont plus éparses et remontent généralement moins loin dans le temps que pour le français d'Europe. Qui vivra verra, j'imagine.

Comment: Alors pour un Français comme moi qui n'a pas connu l'hiver québécois mais qui a connu une bonne balade à l'embouchure du St-Laurent en pleine marée montante à la mi-octobre, je peux affirmer que "frète" (ou "frette") c'est très froid pour un européen !

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Cette explication d'une origine en *frais* me semble très plausible et alignerait notre *frette* sur le plan bien établi de *toute*, *icitte*, *litte* (? lu mais pas encore entendu), *[faite](https://youtu.be/kuvzwZOleAM?t=42)*...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 > J'emploie aussi régulièrement "frais" pour "froid", mais pas en superlatif, au contraire, plutôt en remplacement de "frisquet"

Comment: @LaurentS. Très pertinente remarque, qui représente aussi je crois la manière unique de percevoir *frais* au Québec. Ça vaut le coup de l'ajouter à la gradation proposée dans la question, d'ailleurs. Merci!

Comment: @LukeSawczak À cause de votre remarque, j'en suis maintenant à me demander si *icitte* est aussi plus ici qu'*ici*... ;~)

Answer (score 4):

En tant que Français de France qui n'a vécu que 3 mois au Québec, j'ai toujours compris "frète" comme un euphémisme pour "très froid" et souvent dans l'idée (comme dans la définition) qu'on est surpris parce qu'il fait plus froid que prévu !

Donc je dirais que, oui "frète" est plus froid que "froid" ou, en tout cas, véhicule le fait qu'on est surpris par la température.

Comment: Merci pour cette subtile observation. Il me semble en effet que la surprise s'exprime bien plus spontanément par *frète*. Je n'avais jamais remarqué, mais ça me semble très recevable. Ça ne cerne pas complètement son domaine d'application et ne clôt pas la question, mais ça montre au moins qu'il existe une nuance qui soit propre à *frète* même pour moi qui prétendais ne pas percevoir de différence entre les deux termes.

Answer (score 4):

Davantage un commentaire sur la troisième question qu'une réponse (je n'ai ni l'expérience ni l'expertise pour répondre au deux premières et à l'écrit un *ngram* est « contaminé » par le mot [*frette*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/frette/0) pour le « cercle métallique ») :

> Est-il possible de donner les raisons, probables ou possibles, qui ont
>   conduit à cette gradation (tiède-frais-froid-frète) plutôt qu’à
>   l’autre possible (tiède-frais-frette-froid) ?)

« Le français populaire dit encore [frɛ] pour froid dans l'Ouest et [[frɛt]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/frette) au Canada » (LBU14§60R2) ; on le trouve aussi en [francoprovençal](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fr%C3%A8#Francoproven%C3%A7al). Le Wiktionnaire indique pour le [nom](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/frette#Nom_commun_3) en effet que « certaines personnes distinguent ce mot comme étant un froid plus intense que froid ». Il se trouve que ce mot (*frette*) soit l'ancienne prononciation [frɛt] du mot courant aujourd'hui (*froid*, [fʁwa]). Il se pourrait peut-être qu'en Europe certaines personnes disent un truc comme « il fait tellement/très/si [frɛ] » et qu'ils pensent dire le mot *frais* alors qu'en fait il s'agirait de l'ancienne prononciation ou prononciation populaire pour *froid*, indépendamment de l'idée de gradation *frais/froid/fre(tte)* ; je n'en sais rien. C'est même possible au Québec puisque le [phénomène](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Consonnes) participe d'une ensemble de prononciations particulières pour les mots dont la finale est en -t (les t muets à la fin de certains mot sont prononcés.).

Je connais les adjectifs frais, froid et *frette* mais je n'écrirais jamais le dernier dans un texte qui ne rapporte pas l'oral ou autrement qu'en italiques ou entre guillemets et c'est significatif dans mon usage. Ça signifie que pour moi c'est simplement une prononciation provenant d'un registre ou d'un niveau de langage différent, davantage populaire ou familier, qui constitue chez moi (personnellement) une tendance vers le basilecte. Et pour une raison que je ne saurais expliquer ça amplifie la valeur ou l'intensité du froid parce que c'est plus expressif, plus pittoresque, et c'est ça qui créé l'amplification, pas la sémantique ou la lexicalisation comme telle. Ça me rappelle l'expression *péter au frette* (jamais *au froid*), pour *se briser à cause du froid, mourir, faire un crise cardiaque, de nerfs* etc. (Wiktionnaire), d'emploi populaire ; *frette* c'est comme un « mot-expression ». Plus généralement, je compare ça à la prononciation du substantif *vrai* qui normalement est [vʁɛ] est qui devient [vʁa] chez moi avec le même niveau de langue que *frette* pour marquer ; un [vʁa] est plus fort qu'*un vrai* (dans le sens de *un vrai de vrai*, *un vrai homme*, *un vrai char* etc.). J'ai toujours de la difficulté à qualifier ces phénomènes [phonétiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois)-là (une forme de diphtongaison peut-être ?).

En ce qui a trait à l'exemple du Journal de Québec où l'on trouve froid et *frette* dans la même phrase avec cette gradation, j'assimile ça à une figure de style basée sur la [répétition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_de_style), qui peut ressembler à certains égards à la [figure dérivative](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_d%C3%A9rivative), à l'[accumulation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_(rh%C3%A9torique)) ou à une forme de [polyptote](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyptote), voire de [périssologie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9rissologie) selon qu'on se place sous l'angle graphique, morpho-syntactique ou sémantique. De prime abord il s'agit de [synonymes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/froid#Synonymes), mais en les comparant directement ou indirectement dans le discours, on amplifie le deuxième terme ou on créé un degré plus grand du premier avec le deuxième. Quand le terme se trouve seul, l'intensité est créée davantage par l'emploi d'une formule avec *maudit/un juron* et par l'intonation qu'avec la sémantique particulière qu'aurait le mot (*maudit*/[juron] *qu'il fait froid/frette !!*).

---

- Les prononciations [frɛ], [frɛt] et [fʁwa] peuvent référer au même mot (froid) à l'oral.
- Le langage populaire est plus expressif et je perçois ce qui est plus expressif comme étant plus fort ou intense ; au Québec j'associe *frette* au langage populaire et ça peut donc expliquer pourquoi ça peut être perçu comme plus intensément froid que *froid*.
- La gradation de l'intensité qu'on remarque quand on a les deux termes dans une même phrase pourrait relever de l'effet d'une figure de style basée sur la répétition davantage que de la sémantique des mots.

Comment: Bon j'ai employé _frette_, le GPFC dit _frète_, blanc bonnet, bonnet blanc.

Answer (score 3):

Pour un marin, quand le vent et la pluie arrivent et apportent un refroidissement supportable qui ne demande pas de changer de tenue, « il fait frais ».

Si la température décroît, et qu’en général la tempête grimpe l’échelle de Beaufort, on dit *grand frais*, mais *froid* n’est pas dans le langage quand les déferlantes commencent à submerger le pont.

Le Québec date du temps des trois mâts, *frais* se prononçait alors *frète* en Saintonge, pays de Rochefort, fabrique des bateaux de La Marine Royale…

Le froid sec dans un paysage enneigé est beaucoup plus supportable sur terre que sur une vergue à serrer la toile par grand frais.

---

*Complément après commentaire*

*Frète* n’est pas plus employé sur la façade atlantique qu’à l’ouest de la Belle Province.

Comment: «Frète» est assez utilisé à la grandeur de la province. Le peuplement européen de la province s'est fait de l'est vers l'ouest, mais le vocabulaire marin a persisté dans la vie courante même lorsque la migration a porté les gens loin de la mer et du Saint-Laurent. Le contraste froid/frète, par contre, ne me vient pas de l'enfance. J'en ai pris connaissance plus tard dans ma vie, au contact de gens qui ne provenaient pas de ma région.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 — Ayant vécu plus près de Rochefort-sur-mer que de Montréal, j’aurais peut-être dû dire "la façade atlantique", pour dire  ce que l’on "voit" du Canada quand on s’embarque dans l’embouchure de la Charente … et vous me faites découvrir ce que l’on ressent quand on arrive … on voyage plus vite avec Internet qu’en armant un trois mâts :-)

Comment: @Survenant9r7 — Ce sont là les risques et périls de l’Aventure ou notre Google est un avatar du Poséidon d’Ulysse :-)

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi en France métropolitaine, il y a par ordre croissant: Frette > Froid > Frais

- Frais: Indique un état de fraîcheur, ou une température assez basse.  [Source](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/frais#fr-adj)
- Froid: Très frais. Qui est privé de chaleur, ou de température basse. [Source](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/froid#fr)
- Frette: Très froid. Utilisé pour parler d'un froid plutôt intense. [Source](http://www.je-parle-quebecois.com/lexique/definition/frette.html)

---

### [Étymologie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/frette) de l'adjectif "frette":

> Du latin [frigidus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/frigidus#la) (« froid ») qui donne, en ancien français freid
>   attesté en 1121 : freid leu, « dépourvu de chaleur » (St Brandan, éd.
>   E.G.R. Waters, 1397).
>   L’évolution vers la forme fraide, fraid ou fré,
>   frette est régulière → voir raide et roide de rigidus, mais critiquée,
>   à la fin du XVIIIe siècle car non « parisienne » par Jean-François
>   Féraud : « On dit, dans le *Dictionnaire Gram*. que froid se prononce de
>   deux manières : froa et frè, que la première est du style soutenu, et
>   l'aûtre de la conversation.
>   Tout le monde, il s'en faut bien, n'est
>   pas de cet avis ; et les Litérateurs et critiques les plus estimés,
>   veulent qu'on prononce toujours froa. » — (Dictionaire critique de la
>   langue française, 1787-88)

Edit: Par ailleurs je viens de tomber sur cette image:

[image]

Dont la source est [ATMOSPHERE - Province de Québec](https://www.facebook.com/Atmosphere.ca/photos/a.275269329191926/1742915312427313/?type=3&theater)

Comment: L’image est intéressante et une illustration que ce n'est en effet pas partout au Québec que, comme chez moi, frette peut égaler froid (par exemple, on dit ici indifféremment le robinet d'eau froide ou le robinet d'eau frète) ou même carrément prendre la place de froid (l'expression de la fraîcheur d'une matinée passe le plus souvent directement de «c'est frais à matin» à «c'est frette à matin», sans transition par le terme froid).